# Access SQL distinct single field

Tags: sql, ms-access

Good morning,

I would like to create a query to get . I already read about the "distinct" SQL function but I don't get it done. What I want is a total of all unique "ID_Projekte_FK" based on a date criteria (example >=#01.01.2018#) and grouped by "Bezeichnung".

This is my query

[image]

and my SQL code looks like this

```
SELECT tbl_Werkzeugtypen.Bezeichnung, Count(tbl_Projekte_Phasen.ID_Projekte_FK) AS AnzahlvonID_Projekte_FK
FROM tbl_Projekte_Phasen INNER JOIN (tbl_Projekte INNER JOIN tbl_Werkzeugtypen ON tbl_Projekte.Werkzeugtyp = tbl_Werkzeugtypen.ID_Werkzeugtypen) ON tbl_Projekte_Phasen.ID_Projekte_FK = tbl_Projekte.ID_Projekte
WHERE (((tbl_Projekte_Phasen.Out)>=#1/1/2018#))
GROUP BY tbl_Werkzeugtypen.Bezeichnung
HAVING (((tbl_Werkzeugtypen.Bezeichnung)<>"Entwicklungsprojekt"));
```

Hope you get what I am trying to do.

Comment: about your `query`: _The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions._ I do not see you use aggregate functions like `count`, `sum`...

Comment: the black marked field is "count" (using the German Version of Access 2013). Don't know why its not shown in SQL

Comment: I mean you should use _having_ with one of the aggregate functions. for example: `having count(ID_Projekte_FK) > 0`

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you provide more details about the problem you are getting?

Comment: sure, the table "tbl_Projekte_Phasen" contains several records for a specific project declared in "tbl_Projekte" and linked by "ID_Projekte_Fk -- ID_Projekte". I would like to count all records grouped by "Bezeichnung" from the table "tbl_Werkzeugtypen". If there are 2 records on the table "tbl_Projekte_Phase" for same "ID_Projekte_FK" within the desired date range (criteria) it should count only once.


Example (Bezeichnung | ID_Projekte_FK)
SOLO | K250
SNAP | K251
COFA | K252
SOLO | K253
SOLO | K250

--> this should give me SNAP (1 count), COFA (1 count), SOLO (2 counts)

Comment: Build an aggregate query that groups the records. Then build another query referencing the first that counts those records.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did now .... really need some more practice :/

Anyway, thank you all for your help :)